# Return name of a range

Tags: vba, excel

The data in `A1:C10` is named as `DATA`. How can I get this name using excel macro?

`Range("A1:C10").Name` and `Range("A1:C10").Names` do not work...

Anyone knows what's the formula for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one:

```
MsgBox Range("A1:C10").Name.Name
```

> but I need to store the name in some cell value..how can I do with this

next code stores name of `A1:C10` range in cell `D1`:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("D1") = .Range("A1:C10").Name.Name
End With
```

Comment: Hi! Thx for your reply! but I need to store the name in some cell value..how can I do with this? @simoco

Comment: Hi! I tried this one, but it seems not working..the returned value is 0...@simoco

Comment: try something like this `Workheets("Sheet1").Range("D1") = Workheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C10").Name.Name` (change `Sheet1` to the sheet name where your range is defined) and make sure that named range is defined exactly for `A1:C10`

Comment: Hi! I put in the sheet name, still not working...the returned value is "".@simoco

Comment: @user2774993 There is a typo in the code. It should be `worksheets`

Comment: @user2774993, Try my test workbook (https://www.dropbox.com/s/vcg7p9wf2aq7mvz/test_1.xlsm). Run macro `test` (named range in `A1:C10`)